# How to remove the 15 recent items from the history menu in Firefox via userChrome.css?

Tags: firefox

I'm using Pale Moon (25.5.0 x86) but apparently tweaks that use the userChrome.css file are the same as in Firefox.
I tried to remove them using the DOM Inspector, but I couldn't.
I found [this post](http://forums.mozillazine.org/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=2581871) that was very helpful for many other tweaks, ironically that guy removed everything from the History menu except what I'm try to remove now.
I would prefer not installing any add-on.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: I am not asking how to clear the history ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
#history-menu #menu_showAllHistory ~ .bookmark-item {display: none !important;}
```

This will hide the history items on Firefox. If it doesn't on Palemoon, use the DOM Inspector to find the appropriate item(s) to get a selector and change the line above accordingly.

Comment: wooow!
It worked!
And I was all day, restarting the browser, trial and error, trial and error...
Thank you!
btw I'm new here xD

Comment: Hey!
Unfortunately, I just realized that now there is no items on the menus' Recently Closed Tabs' and 'Recently Closed Windows ", do use these submenus but not the others. :(
Screen capture: http://postimg.org/image/r7gilpa6v/

Comment: Is there any way to reduce the number of items on that list, instead of 15, only keep 4 or 6 items?

Comment: @JoséR.Hernández Try the updated CSS selector. It should only hide the history items in the main menu.

Comment: Hey!
I tried again with the new code and it worked!
It seems that this time there is no problem
Gracias!
I would like to ask you where did you learn this?
Because I read a lot about the userChrome.css file but there is no such documentation as one would like, not even by Mozilla.
PD. Sorry about my english... Hablo español! :)

Comment: @JoséR.Hernández I just fired up DOM Inspector and had a look. If you know your CSS it shouldn't be too hard. I tried the selector I came up with by creating a new style with the Stylish extension.